# Why multicategories?

Tags: category-theory, intuition, motivation

Why are multicategories important?

I'm not biased against them, just curious.
Let me clarify:

1. Is there any construction that can be done in a multicategory, but not in a (traditional) category with products, using morphisms $X_1\times \dots\times X_n \to Y$?
2. If the answer to above is no, are multicategories still convenient because there are additional axioms which in traditional categories would instead be conditions that have to be proven? Or at least do multicategories provide a more convenient notation?

I may be completely off the mark here, since I'm far from being an expert.

**Edit:** Instead of the categorical product, we can more generally ask the same question using "any" tensor product, assuming we are in a monoidal category.  (Thanks to Mariano for the helpful comment!)

Comment: Multilinear algebra. A multilinear map is not a linear map defined in the product.

Comment: Well...for that I could repeat the question, but using tensor products. (Right?)

Comment: There is an intrinistic issue around the (lack of) parentheses and coherence axioms in monoidal categories. Afaik, multicategories were one candidate to make it straight.

Comment: @Berci Your comment seems unclear...the necessary coherence conditions are universally agreed on and have been understood since the definition of monoidal categories. Multicategories save some bookkeeping work, that's all.

Comment: If we have a bunch of (possibly noncommutative) groups $G_1,\dots,G_n$, is there a universal function $G_1\times\dots\times G_n\rightarrow A$ which is a homomorphism in each argument? I don't know, but multicategories help you ask the question.

Comment: It seems one motivation for multicategories is answering the question of "where do the coherences in monoidal categories come from?"  The multicategory answer is universality.

Answer (score 2):

The multicategories which arise from a tensor product are usally said to be "representable". In fact, even in these cases it is usally more natural to define first the multicategory structure; the tensor is then characterized by its universal property with respect to multimaps (the associative and coherence properties of tensor follow from that).
For a non-representable example, you may consider a full multicategory of a representable one; for instance, take the one-object multicategory which consists of a set and all its endomultimappings (internal operations).
For another natural instance, consider (for any category C) the multicategory with the same objects as C and with finite sequences of maps in C with a common target as multimaps; it is representable iff C has finite sums.